# Flattening JSONB array in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am using Postgres 9.4 and storing my data in as JSONB arrays. I am looking for a way to extract json elements inside the array and replace them with one concatenated json element using psql. Consider as example following table:

```
'aaa' | [{"a":"foo"},{"b":"bar"},{"c":["baz", 'boom']}]  | 404
'bbb' | [{"bar":"foo"}]                                  | 501
```

What I am looking to achieve is:

```
'aaa' | {"a":"foo", "b":"bar", "c":["baz", "boom"]}     | 404
'bbb' | {"bar":"foo"}                                   | 501
```

I have tried to achieve it using builtin postgres functions for json types. But I only figured out how to extract elements at the exact position. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  id, jo.obj
FROM    mytable
CROSS JOIN
        LATERAL
        (
        SELECT  JSON_OBJECT_AGG(jt.key, jt.value) obj
        FROM    JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data) je
        CROSS JOIN
                LATERAL JSONB_EACH(je.value) jt
        ) jo
```