# postgresql json: keys as values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I just discovered the json capabilities of postgresql but have trouble understanding how to generate json with queries. I hope the question I am asking makes sense and please excuse me if I am missing something obvious.

my problem ? how to generate json with some values being keys to others. 
here an example

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table  my_table(id int, sale_year int, sale_qty int);

insert into my_table values (10, 2007, 2);
insert into my_table values (10, 2008, 1);
insert into my_table values (10, 2009, 0);
insert into my_table values (20, 2009, 2);
insert into my_table values (30, 2011, 1);
insert into my_table values (30, 2012, 3);
```

The following statement

```
SELECT id, json_agg(to_json(my_table)) FROM public.my_table group by id;
```

gives me a json per id (e.g. for id = 20)

```
 20, [{"id":20, "sale_year": 2009, "sale_qty": 2}]
```

my question is:

is it possible to return a json with the following structure ?

```
  {"2009": 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select id, json_agg(json_build_object(sale_year, sale_qty))
from my_table
group by id
order by id;
```

This returns:

```
id | json_agg                                  
---+-------------------------------------------
10 | [{"2007" : 2}, {"2008" : 1}, {"2009" : 0}]
20 | [{"2009" : 2}]                            
30 | [{"2011" : 1}, {"2012" : 3}]
```

Comment: fantastic. THANKS a lot.

Comment: will it be possible to have as result a jsonb with key values and not a list ? so {"2007" : 2, "2008" : 1, "2009" : 0} and not [{"2007" : 2}, {"2008" : 1}, {"2009" : 0}] ? should I ask this in another question ?

Answer (score 0):

**I hope that this will help someone else**

in some cases, one would want to get, not an **array of jsonb data** but a single jsonb element.

inspired from this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704489/f) this is an example of how to do it

```
with tx1
as
(
 select 
 * 
 from 
 (values 
 (10, 2007, 2), 
 (10, 2008, 1),
 (10, 2009, 0),
 (20, 2009, 2),
 (30, 2011, 1),
 (30, 2012, 3))
 as t (id, sale_year, sale_qty)),
 tx2
 as
 (select id, 
  jsonb_agg(json_build_object(sale_year, sale_qty)) as x_data
  from tx1
  group by id
  order by id)
  SELECT  
  id, 
  x_data,
  jo.obj
  FROM    tx2
  CROSS JOIN
    LATERAL
    (
    SELECT  JSON_OBJECT_AGG(jt.key, jt.value) obj
    FROM    JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(x_data) je
    CROSS JOIN
            LATERAL JSONB_EACH(je.value) jt
    ) jo
```

This gives

```
 { "2007" : 2, "2008" : 1, "2009" : 0 }
 { "2011" : 1, "2012" : 3 }
```